# Starting a mysql prompt

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, terminal

I am trying to start a new rails project using mysql but I am having difficulties with mysql. So this is what I am trying to do..

```
Rails new name -d mysql
```

Then I try this..

```
rake db:create
```

but it gives me the following error..

```
    #<Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)>
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"biller_development"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
#<Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)>
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"biller_test"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

Then I try this..

```
mysql -uroot
```

for the mysql prompt but it says the command wasn't found. I Have mysql 5.6 installed and i have mysql workbench. What should I do? any help would be appreciated..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what linux distro are you using, maybe you have mariadb or something like that

Comment: I am using a Mac Yosemite OS

Comment: Check your mysql installation and then match your settings on ``config/database.yml`` to match your mysql installation.